# Solving $u_{xx}+u_{x}^{2}=ku$ for various k

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Here is a nonlinear ODE: $u_{xx}+u_{x}^{2}=ku$ for various k

**Attempts**

For $k=0$, we have $u=log(x+c_{1})+c_{2}$. For $k\neq 0$,

1)Divide by $u_{x}$ and integrate both sides to get:

$$log(u_{x})+u=k\int \frac{1}{[log(u)]'}dx=kg(x),$$

where $g\circ logu(x)=x$. Not sure if that helps, but it is cool nonetheless.

2)since there is no x, we can invert things and set $v=u_{x}$ to get:

$$w_{u}(u)=2u\frac{1}{v(x(u))}-v(x(u)),$$

where $w(u)=v(x(u))$. But no interesting cancelation happened.

3)Using $e^{\int P(x)dx}$ we get

$$P_{x}+P^{2}+P_{x}^{2}e^{\int P dx}=k\Rightarrow$$
$$1+\frac{P^{2}}{P_{x}}+P_{x}e^{\int Pdx}=\frac{k}{P_{x}}.$$

Here we are faced with that $e^{\int Pdx }$ term.

4)Using test fcn $\phi$

$$\int (u_{x}+u_{x}u)\phi_{x}+uu_{xx}\phi dx=k\int u \phi dx,$$

but not much.

5)Using $u(x)=\sum c_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ we get

$$\sum c_{n} \frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+\sum b_{n}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=k\sum c_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\Rightarrow$$

by the cauchy product $b_{n}=\sum^{n}c_{k}c_{n-k}$. So equating coefficients we get

$$c_{n+2} +\sum^{n+1}c_{k}c_{n-k}=kc_{n}.$$

Interesting, system of eqns.

6)Taking fourier transform gives us coupled $\widehat{u^{2}_{x}}$, which we can't simplify.

7)Taking $z=ln(u)$ we get

$$log(z')=z+e^{-z}+\frac{k}{z'}+C.$$

interesting, but not sure how to separate.

any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2=ku$$
An usual way to reduce the order of such ODE of autonomous kind is the change of variable : $\frac{du}{dx}=y(u)$ hense $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=y\frac{dy}{du}$
$$y\frac{dy}{du}+y^2=ku$$
Let $Y(u)=y^2$
$$\frac{dY}{du}+2Y=2ku$$
The solution of this first order linear ODE is :
$$Y=ce^{-2u}+ku-\frac{k}{2}$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=y=\pm\sqrt{ce^{-2u}+ku-\frac{k}{2}}$$
$$x=\pm \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{c\;e^{-2u}+ku-\frac{k}{2}}}$$
In general (for any $k$) this integral cannot be expressed on a simpler closed form. So, the above integal itself can be considered as an implicite closed form for the solution of the ODE and this gives the general answer of the question.

In the particular case $k=0$ :
$$x=\pm \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{c\;e^{-2u}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}e^u+c_2$$
$$u=c_1+\ln|x-c_2|$$

Some particular solutions can be found for $c=0$ :
$$x=\pm \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{ku-\frac{k}{2}}}=\pm 2 \sqrt{\frac{2u-1}{2k}}+c_2$$
$$u=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{4}(x-c_2)^2$$